# input field type=date in hta file

Tags: hta

is there a way to use `<input type="date" />` in .hta file?

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />` does not solve the problem.
It works like a normal "text" field for me.

Comment: No, there isn't. IE never implemented date type of the input element. If you really need this, you've to implement your own date picker, or find a library for IE.

Comment: The IE Engine used by MSHTA predates the introduction of [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#date-state-typedate) so no without your own implementation it isn’t possible.